# ui.bootstrap popover-is-open doesn't work properly

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want not to show ui.bootstrap popover by using popover-is-open directive. For example, in template:

```
  <button class="fa fa-link add-link" 
    uib-popover="popover" 
    popover-is-open="isOpen"> Show popover </i>
```

And in controller:

```
angular.module('demoModule').controller('PopoverDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.isOpen = false;      
});
```

See [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/gnXOgSgdjAiCiFbINGBp?p=preview)

I am expecting that popover should never be opened, but it opens on click on it. It seems that popover-is-open affects only first angular compiling. Any ideas?

**upd:** Actually, i want not to show popover only in some cases, in other cases it should be shown. For example, i have download-dialog popover and i want to show it only if size of file is greater than some limit.

Answer (score 6):

The `popover-is-open` is only for the initial behavior, i.e. if it evaulates to `true`, then the popover opens instantly even without a click. If you change the value of `isOpen` to `true` in your plunkr, you see that ([my example plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XIFTbpKK6TfmYXNQZJYs)).

What you want is the `popover-enable` attribute:

```
<button class="fa fa-link add-link" 
 uib-popover="popover" 
 popover-enable="isOpen">Show popover</button>
```

**Update for the question update:**

You are free to evaluate any boolean expression in the `popover-enable` attribute instead of the static `isOpen` which always evaulates to `false` in your example.

I have created an [advanced plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/evGPIOLfLMuXnuBeoM81) to show that:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="downloadSize">
<button class="fa fa-link add-link" 
 uib-popover="popover" 
 popover-enable="isOpen()">Show popover</button>
```

with the controller code

```
$scope.isOpen = function() { return $scope.downloadSize > 100; }
```

You have a new text box where you can enter a number to simulate the download size. When it gets `> 100`, the popup will be enabled.

Comment: You are right, but what if i want not to open popover only in some cases? For example, i have download dialog and i want to show it only if size of file is greater than, for example, 100Mb?

Comment: You are free to evaluate any boolean condition for the `popover-enable` attribute. I will updated my answer with an example.

Comment: this is an old topic but still I think it needs be stated that the first statement "The popover-is-open is only for the initial behavior, i.e. if it evaulates to true, then the popover opens instantly even without a click." is not correct. you can see the use of `popover-is-open` in [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/Sc17SsLUFKPlKBW0KvfS?p=preview) plunker.

Answer (score 2):

In order to handle the open state whit the `popover-is-open` value you must set `popover-trigger="none"` or maybe `popover-trigger="'none'"`. As it says in the [docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#popover)

> Using the 'none' trigger will disable the internal trigger(s), one can
>   then use the popover-is-open attribute exclusively to show and hide
>   the popover.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 $scope.$apply(function () {

$scope.isOpen = false;     

});
```

method for applying this property